# Typescript extended classes, Parent-Child relations problems

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am creating a set of classes Parent/Child that are extended to SubParent/SubChild. I would like that the typescript knew that when we get the parent from a child instance we obtain a Parent instance, while if we get the parent from a SubChild, we will obtain a SubParent instance.

Here the code so it is easier to understand:

```
// @ts-ignore
export default class Parent<T extends Child = Child> {
    protected readonly m_child: T;

    protected constructor(builder: new (p: Parent) => T) {
        this.m_child = new builder(this);
    }

    public static init() {
        return new Parent(Child);
    }

    public get child(): T {
        return this.m_child;
    }

    /**
     * Parent actions
     */
}


// @ts-ignore
export default class SubParent<T extends SubChild = SubChild> extends Parent<T> {

    protected constructor(builder: new (p: SubParent) => T) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public static init() {
        return new SubParent(SubChild);
    }

    /**
     * Sub parent actions
     */
}
```

The child classes:

```
// @ts-ignore
export default class Child<T extends Parent = Parent> {
    private readonly m_parent: T;

    public constructor(animal: T) {
        this.m_parent = animal;
    }

    public get parent(): T {
        return this.m_parent;
    }

    /**
     * Child actions
     */
}


// @ts-ignore
export default class SubChild<T extends SubParent = SubParent> extends Child<T> {
    /**
     * Sub child actions
     */
}
```

In this example I have had to add the **@ts-ignore** which I am pretty sure should not be required. But without it I am getting: [Type parameter 'T' has a circular default].

And I would also love that the typescript knew the type of instance we are treating on each class:

```
const parent = Parent.init();           // ts knows this is a Parent instance
const subParent = SubParent.init(); // ts knows this is a SubParent instance


const child = parent.child;             // ts knows this is a Child instance
const subChild = subParent.child;   // ts knows this is a SubChild instance
 

const child2 = child.parent;             // ts NOT knows this is a Parent instance
const subChild2 = subChild.parent;   // ts NOT knows this is a SubParent instance
```

Comment: Please [edit] this post to ask [a single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post); you are currently asking about removing ts-ignore as one question, and about types of instances as a second question.  If you really want to ask both you should move one of them to a separate post.  Which question do you want to address here?

Comment: Note, for the first question, [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2eBW) is all I can currently think of to do, since generic defaults cannot depend on themselves.  I will keep thinking about it.

Comment: Aside: you are using the term "Super" to refer to **Sub**classes, and this is confusing.  Could you change that?  And in `new (Parent) => T`, are you intending `Parent` to be the name of the dummy parameter of type `any`?  Or do you mean `new (p: Parent) => T`?  They are different and that difference might be important for static side compatibility

Comment: At this point I have [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NVbbnN) which is as close as I can get to what you want for both parts of your question.  When you've finished [edit]ing the post to ask just one question and possibly clean up any other issues (super vs sub and `(Parent)` vs `(p: Parent)`) I can write up an answer.  Let me know via a comment.

Comment: I have edited my post from super to sub. And after a first sight to your code example I think it is really good and it could be exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you address this: "And in `new (Parent) => T`, are you intending `Parent` to be the name of the dummy parameter of type `any`? Or do you mean `new (p: Parent) => T`? They are different and that difference might be important for static side compatibility"

Comment: I did mean "new (p: Parent) => T". I have edited my post

Comment: But now what you are doing [is not verifiably safe](https://tsplay.dev/N5zx5m).  A `Parent`'s constructor accepts any `Parent`-accepting class, but `SubParent` requires a `SubParent`-accepting class.  There's no guarantee that the latter is the former.  Presumably `new builder(this)` will always be fine, but there are probably situations where it wouldn't be.  I'm happy to write up the answer with that caveat, as long as you're okay with it.

Comment: mmmm. yes I am more than happy with your actual answer. Thank you!